Input that .repeat() takes in Gatling simulation
I have a scenario where for array size I need to repeat some code piece in Gatling.
While .repat() works with integer provided for items.size.toInt , it does not honour the provided value and repeat just once.

Please share a minimal reproducible code sample.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
